# Week beginning and end PHP

Tags: php, date

Say I wanted to get the week beginning and ending, for example:

```
Mon 29th June - week start
Sun 5th July - week end
and then tomorrow (Mon 6th July) it will say:
Mon 6th July - week start
Sun 12th July - week end
```

Is this the right way to do it?

```
$week_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last monday'));
$week_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this sunday'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime class has this nice method called [`setIsoDate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php):

```php
$start = new DateTime();
$start->setIsoDate($start->format('o'), $start->format('W'));
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('+6 day');

echo "From: " . $start->format('Y-m-d') . " to: " . $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/392667)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

That would not work properly if the current date is Monday. `last monday` would then translate to the Monday the previous week.

I would use this syntax instead:

```
$week_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last monday', strtotime('tomorrow')));
$week_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this sunday'));
```

---

You might also consider avoiding those "advanced" relative formats, and seek the correct dates based on the current weekday. Might be a bit more reliable, as those week formats don't always seem to behave as one might expect, and the logic behind them isn't readily available.

This solution uses simpler `strtotime` formats, and instead puts the seek logic in the code itself. As such, it's a lot more predictable, if a little less elegant.

```
$weekday = date("N"); // 1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday
$week_start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-" . ($weekday - 1) . " days"));
$week_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+" . (7 - $weekday) . " days"));
```

Note that the `date("N")` flag is only available in PHP 5.1 and later. For older version you'd need to use `date("w")`, and move the Sunday value to the back.

```
$weekday = date("w"); // 0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday
if ($weekday == 0) {
    $weekday = 7;
}
```

Comment: This outputs 2015-07-06 - 2015-07-12 which is incorrect as start should be 29th June and end should be 5th July.

Comment: maybe "monday this week - 7 days"?

Comment: Kind of looks like your server is a day ahead. Could that be? What does a straight up `date("Y-m-d")` return?
On my test server (set to UTC) this returns the expected results: '2015-06-29' and '2015-07-05'.

Comment: Yes, the server time is currently 5 July.

Comment: Odd. I managed to replicate your results on another server. Not sure what causes the difference. - However I came up with another solution that works on both sides. I've edited the answer with that. I did some tests and it appears to work regardless of timezones, localizations or PHP versions.